# Как правильно зашифровать параметр в URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день! Есть MVC сайт. Для просмотра некоторой информации, передаются в строке uRL 2 параметра: а) лицевой счет, б) номер телефона, таким образом:

```
~/?id=12343&tel=79998884565
```

Мне необходимо зашифровать эти параметры, чтобы никто другой не понял, что передается на сервер. Пока остановился на таком варианте: Сгенерировал ключ для шифрования и расшифровки. Шифрую таким образом:

```
public static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string sEncryptionKey)
    {
        byte[] key = { };
        byte[] IV = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 };
        byte[] inputByteArray;
        try
        {
            key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey.Substring(0, 8));
            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

или же таким, без задания вектора:

```
public string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string sEncryptionKey)
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        DES.Key = hashMD5.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey));
        DES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform DESEncrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
        Buffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
        string TripleDES = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypt.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length));
        return TripleDES;
    }
```

в принципе меня всё устраивало бы, но в разных вариантах шифрования (используя разные входящие строки номеров), получается нечто похожее "eBCBbTjZyYg+jztO/NIqvg==", при обработке контроллера в данной последовательности знак "+" заменяется на пробел.
Каким образом можно сделать так,чтобы при попадании в контроллер параметр не менялся, чтобы "+" оставался и возможно другие нежелательные последовательности символов?
Или же,как то по другому шифровать, чтобы не было в шифрованном виде знаков "+/==;?&", которые могут не понравится asp.

Comment: Ну если шифрование устраивает, то смотрите в сторону [Uri.EscapeDataString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) и [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx). На enso см. например [такой вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/602642/5752652).

Comment: Спасибо! Я правильно понимаю, когда генерю ссылку для клиента, делаю HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt("79888884565","KEYsmdlkfasnf")) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте HttpUtility.UrlEncode для кодирования, а HttpUtility.UrlDecode - для декодирования обратно.

```
var asdf1 = "eBCBbTjZyYg+jztO/NIqvg==";
var asdf2 = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(asdf1); // eBCBbTjZyYg%2bjztO%2fNIqvg%3d%3d
var asdf3 = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(asdf2); // eBCBbTjZyYg+jztO/NIqvg==
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Единственное в отладке увидел, когда закодированное (urlencode + зашифрованное) url попадает в контроллер, то не нужно дополнительно делать URLDecode, в данном случае сразу в контроллере вижу //eBCBbTjZyYg+jztO/NIqvg==